# Почему @RequestParam отсутствует

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, редирект

есть метод который вернет ответы с помощью `id`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAnswerByQuestionId",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAnswerByQuestionId(ModelMap map,@RequestParam("id")int id){
    List<Answer> findAllBYQuestionId=answerRepository.findAllByQuestionId(id);
    map.addAttribute("findAllAnswersByQuestionId",findAllBYQuestionId);
    map.addAttribute("addAnswer",new Answer());
    return "answerResult";
}
```

этот метод идет в JSP сюда

```
<spring:form action="/addAnswer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="addAnswer">
<c:forEach items="${findAllAnswersByQuestionId}" var="name">
    ${name.text}
<input type="hidden" value="${name.id}" name="questionId">

</c:forEach>
    <spring:textarea path="text"></spring:textarea>
    <input type="file" name="pict">
    <input type="submit" value="add">

</spring:form>
```

на втором строке печатает результат. В этом JSP под результатом есть форма для добавлении ответа. Когда все ок - добавили ответ, данные идут сюда

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAnswer",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addAnswer(@ModelAttribute("answer")Answer answer,@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails,@RequestParam("questionId")int id,@RequestParam("pict")MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File(imageUploadPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            String picName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            File picture = new File("D:\\bankSystem\\" + picName);
            file.transferTo(picture);
            answer.setImage(picName);
            answer.setUserUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
            answer.setQuestionId(id);
        }
        answerRepository.save(answer);
        return "redirect:/getAnswerByQuestionId";

    }
```

Здесь добавляется и идет обратно на этот метод `getAnswerByQuestionId`, чтобы пользователь добавил еще один ответ либо увидел его ответ. Проблема в том, что когда идет обратно на этот метод `getAnswerByQuestionId` возникает ошибка

```
request param id is not present
```

вот скажет, что не давали `id`, чтобы он смог печатать результат. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не давать `id` и войти на этот JSP?

Comment: если возникает ошибка, то должно быть исключение

Comment: В консоль нечего не дает

Comment: В чем тогда ошибка?

Comment: request param id is not present это дает на браузере а в консоль нечего не дает а этот ошибка дает когда идешь обратно к методу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр можно передать с помощью `RedirectAttributes`.  Когда вы делаете перенаправление запроса, то необходимо чтобы требуемые параметры находились в url.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAnswer",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAnswer(@ModelAttribute("answer")Answer answer,
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails,
                        @RequestParam("questionId")int id,
                        @RequestParam("pict")MultipartFile[] files,
                        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
  ....
  redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", id);
  return "redirect:/getAnswerByQuestionId";
}
```

---

Для более детального ознакомления см. [документацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

Comment: пожалуйста дайте пример я что то не очень понял именно куда надо давать параметр

Comment: надеюсь что так будет понятно

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам благодарю вам спасибо большое